# Setting the page number to one after each use of `\chapter` after the `\appendix'

Tags: numbering, appendices

The following code resets the page number after each use of the `\chapter` after the `\appendix` and produces A-0, A-1, ..., B-0, B-1, ...
However, how I make it A-1, A-2, ...., B-1, B-2, ...

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{page}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `chappg` package. It probably does what you want.